# d3 .filter function stops while matching string values in two arrays when a 'no match' occurs

Tags: arrays, html, d3.js, local-storage, filtering

Intent: 
Match strings from localStorage with strings in array from .csv and change style when there is a match.

All available words are in two different .csv files. In localStorage some of the words, either from file 1 or from file 2, are stored.
On page refresh either csv-list 1 or csv-list 2 is displayed, not both together.

The following code gets strings from localStorage:

```
retrieveMarks = window.localStorage.getItem("marked")
      wup = JSON.parse(retrieveMarks);
      console.log("hi" + wup)
```

and displays correctly in the console:

```
hicsalád,nő,bank,hal,kabát,baba,vasútállomás,étel,ügyvéd,banán,diák,gyermek,energia
```

I am now using this list in a filter, successfully matching against a second array d `( strings from .csv );` changing the style successfully and as intended:

```
console.log(d3.selectAll(".bubble-label-name").filter((d) -> textValue(d) in wup).style("border", "6px solid red"))
```

The problem:

Instance 1: `the values (d) -> textValue(d)` are loaded from First.csv file; everything works fine; all the matching strings have the desired effect

Instance 2:`the values (d) -> textValue(d)` are loaded from the Second.csv file, the style change does not occur anymore.

My interpretation:
The filter `.filter((d) -> textValue(d) in sup)` starts matching at the beginning of the localStorage array. When it does not find a string, progression stops. The filter does not evaluate the second word from localStorage etc..

Is this correct ? What code is needed to progress filtering when a no-match occurs, skipping to the next match ?

Comment: No, your interpretation does not seem to be correct. `.filter` does not stop at the first match or non-match. The problem lies elsewhere, and from the looks of it, in the part of the code which extracts the words from `Second.csv`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

Please see the solution here. Getting the value fro two different cvs was not really an issue, just a typo.

d3 localStorage.getItem() compare arrays .filter()